# Error, (in addList) invalid subscript selector

Tags: maple

I have a list of numbers and I want to add them and then multiply them by a constant.

```
addList := proc(a::list,b::integer)::integer;
local x,i,s;
description "add a list of numbers and multiply by a constant";
x:=b;
s:=0;
for i in a do
    s:=s+a[i];
end do;
s:=s*x;
end proc;
```

sumList := addList([2, 2, 3], 2) works fine but at the same time sumList := addList([20, 20, 30], 2) gives an error. 
Can somebody point out the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the for loop you do `s:=s+a[i]` but i is set to one of the values in a already - not the index of a value.  A first pass fix would be to just change the statement above to `s:=s+i`.

You could also write the function as

```
proc(a::list,b::integer)::integer; 
   convert(a,`+`)*b; 
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter, there is

```
addList:= (a,b)-> `+`(a[])*b;
```